# Reverse animation with ScrollMagic

Tags: gsap, scrollmagic

I want to have a section of a webpage controlled by ScrollMagic. Will be a set of slides, pinned and with a fading effect changing them while you scroll the page.

It works when I scroll from top to bottom, but when I reach the end of page and I scroll up, there is no animation.

How can I achieve the same behavior on reverse direction?

```js
 $(function () { 
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
   globalSceneOptions: {
    triggerHook: 'onLeave'
   }
  });

  var slides = document.querySelectorAll("section.panel");

  for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
            var animation = TweenMax.to(slides[i], 1, { autoAlpha: 1, ease: Quad.easeInOut});
            var options = { triggerElement: slides[i] };
            if(i === slides.length-1){
                options['duration'] = 0;
            }
   var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene(options)
    .setPin(slides[i])
                .setTween(animation)
                .addIndicators();
            scene.addTo(controller);
  }
 });
```

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panel.first {
  opacity: 1;
}
.panel.last{
margin-bottom: 400px;
}
.panel .column {
  width: 50%;
}
.panel .column.vertical-center {
  margin: auto 0;
  padding: 0 5em;
}
.panel .column .section-title {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="slide1" class="panel first">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column vertical-center">
    <div class="section-title">
      SLIDE 1
    </div>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide1" class="panel">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column vertical-center">
    <div class="section-title">
      SLIDE 2
    </div>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide1" class="panel">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column vertical-center">
    <div class="section-title">
      SLIDE 3
    </div>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide1" class="panel">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column vertical-center">
    <div class="section-title">
      SLIDE 4
    </div>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide1" class="panel">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column vertical-center">
    <div class="section-title">
      SLIDE 5
    </div>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide6" class="panel last">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column vertical-center">
    <div class="section-title">
      SLIDE 6
    </div>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.6/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scene parameter `reverse` should handle this. It is set to `true` by default and it should play the animations in reverse when scrolling back up. Here is where you set the parameter:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 100,
    triggerHook: 1,
    reverse: true
    });
```

or add it here:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    duration: 100,
    triggerHook: 1
    }).reverse(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to reverse the scroll magic animation:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene(options)
            .setPin(slides[i])
            .setTween(animation)
            .addIndicators();
            .reverse(true); // this will reverse your animation in scrollmagic
        scene.addTo(controller);
```